# using multiple regex to get values from panda dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, regex

i'm still learning python and pandas dataframe.

My goal is to get values(name) from text in dataframe column using regex, but the text doesn't have same pattern so i've come up with multiple regex and i need to validate the result so it's just getting the correct values of name. which in the end made me do a looping over dataframe and regex list.

Here's my attempt in python :

Data:

```
rawdata = ['Current Trending Voice Actress Takahashi Rie was a..',
           'One of the legend voice actor Tsuda Kenjiro is a blabalabla he was',
           'The most popular amongs the fans voice actor Akari Kito is known',
           'From Demon Slayer series voice actor Hanae Natsuki said he was in problem with his friend',
           'Shibuya February 2023, voice actor Yuki Kaji and His wife announced birth of new child they was',
           'Most popular female voice actress Ayane Sakura began',
           'Known as Kirito from SAO Voice Actor Matsuoka Yoshitsugu was'
]
```

the dataframe :

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'text': rawdata})
```

regex list :

```
regex_list = [
    r'(?<=voice actor )(.*)(?= was)',
    r'(?<=voice actor )(.*)(?= is)',
    r'(?<=voice actor )(.*)(?= said)',
    r'(?<=voice actor )(.*)(?= and)'
]
```

the operation :

```
res = []
for ind in df.index:

  for n, rule in enumerate(regex_list):
     result = re.findall(regex_list[n], df['text'][ind], re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
     if result:
       if len(result[0]) > 20:
         result = re.findall(regex_list[n+1], df['text'][ind], re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
       else:
         n = 0
         re.append(result[0])
         break
     if not result and n==len(regex_list)-1:
      re.append('Not Found')
       



df["Result"] = res  
print(df)
```

Result :

```
text               Result
0  Current Trending Voice Actress Takahashi Rie w...            Not Found
1  One of the legend voice actor Tsuda Kenjiro is...        Tsuda Kenjiro
2  The most popular amongs the fans voice actor A...           Akari Kito
3  From Demon Slayer series voice actor Hanae Nat...        Hanae Natsuki
4  Shibuya February 2023, voice actor Yuki Kaji a...            Yuki Kaji
5  Most popular female voice actress Ayane Sakura...            Not Found
6  Known as Kirito from SAO Voice Actor Matsuoka ...  Matsuoka Yoshitsugu
```

The result we're already satisfied me. But my concern is when i'm working with the bigger data and have many regex pattern the process will take a lot of time and resources because it has to do a lot of iterations.

Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: You might use a single pattern matching instead of lookarounds and use the capture group and an alternation, and take the group 1 value `\bvoice actor (.*) (?:was|is|said|and)\b` See https://regex101.com/r/kDa218/1 Note that the `.*` is greedy, if you want to match the first occurrence, you can make it non greedy `.*?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to match your text and get the result directly, using a capturing group around the name characters. You can then use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html?highlight=fillna#pandas.DataFrame.fillna) to replace any non-matches with `Not Found`:

```py
df['Result'] = df['text'].str.extract(r'voice (?:actor|actress)\s+(.*?)\s+(?:is|was|said|and)\b', re.I).fillna('Not Found')
```

Output:

```
                                                                                              text               Result
0                                             Current Trending Voice Actress Takahashi Rie was a..        Takahashi Rie
1                               One of the legend voice actor Tsuda Kenjiro is a blabalabla he was        Tsuda Kenjiro
2                                 The most popular amongs the fans voice actor Akari Kito is known           Akari Kito
3        From Demon Slayer series voice actor Hanae Natsuki said he was in problem with his friend        Hanae Natsuki
4  Shibuya February 2023, voice actor Yuki Kaji and His wife announced birth of new child they was            Yuki Kaji
5                                             Most popular female voice actress Ayane Sakura began            Not Found
6                                     Known as Kirito from SAO Voice Actor Matsuoka Yoshitsugu was  Matsuoka Yoshitsugu
```

Note I have updated your regex to match all the possible following words at once using an alternation and added a `\b` (word boundary) after it to ensure it doesn't match something like `Andrew`:

```
(?:is|was|said|and)\b
```

and also to match `actor` or `actress` the same way:

```
(?:actor|actress)
```

I've also added space matching outside the capture group so the name doesn't need trimming:

```
\s+(.*?)\s+
```